# position: fixed not working on IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem when styling `position: fixed` in CSS but it doesn't appear properly on IE 11.

Please check out my pen here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vjmqwx)

I want to keep `hide-modal` button at the right of the modal, so I set `position: fixed` and `right: 0` to the div. This looks great on most browsers. Unfortunately on IE 11, the button is placed at the right of the body instead of the modal.

Anyone can give me a solution to this problem? I've tried changing the position to absolute but it didn't solve. Thank you.

Comment: `position:fixed` is relative to the browser window, in IE works as expected, I'll look better because I'm not sure how it works your example

Comment: look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730304/position-fixed-close-button-of-bootstrap-modal-styling-is-not-displaying-properl